# stack raster using GDAL and numpy dstack

Tags: python, raster, gdal, numpy

I am testing Savitzky-Golay filter with my MODIS dataset. Currently I am testing for 10 rasters (but later on will use my whole dataset) only just to test how should I create my script. So my initial workflow is to:

1. Access my raster files
2. each file I need to convert to 2D array using GDAL or GDAL Numeric
3. Append all those created 2D arrays to a list
4. Implement numpy.dstack() to stack my 2D arrays and hopefully I can begin some analysis.

However, I getting error in the 4th step (it says memory error) -- converting my list of 2D arrays to a stack. Could you guide me some advice how to proceed. I am just building my script so for now its not so much.

```
import os, sys
import gdal, numpy as np
import gdalnumeric as gd
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

rasters = list()

ws = 'G:/Test/Raster'
for folder, subs, files in os.walk(ws):
    for filename in files:
        aSrc = gd.LoadFile(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        rasters.append(aSrc)

stackRast = np.dstack(rasters)
```

Comment: What is the size of your raster files? You are probably running out of memory due to the big amount of data you are loading, hence the memory error.

Comment: as chkaiser mentioned - perhaps a problem because the rasters are in memory twice? (once during append and another during dstack?). maybe create a np array with the final shape and add each raster to the array as it's read?

Comment: Hi chkaiser and fluidmotion, I tried to revised the script just to test if it really because of memory problem. I change the dstack argument to: stackRast = np.dstack((rasters[0], rasters[1], rasters[2], rasters[3], rasters[4], rasters[5], rasters[6], rasters[7], rasters[8], rasters[9])) and it worked. The shape of my array is (4800, 4800, 10) and if I extract an timeseries value for a particular index it returns an array([1719, 7068, 6958, 6822, 6214, 6534, 6972, 7715, 7113, 7441]). However, my method will not be possible if I will be dealing with approx. 800 rasters. Any advice? Thanks-Leo

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a MemoryError, and there is not much you can do about it unfortunately.
This is a common problem in Python when working on spatial data, as those libraries don't support out-of-core operations (read-write from disk instead of memory).

I would suggest to see if something like this improves your situation:

```
import os, sys
import gdal, numpy as np
import gdalnumeric as gd
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

ws = 'G:/Test/Raster'
try:
    del stackRast
except NameError:
    pass

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(ws):
    for filename in files:
        aSrc = gd.LoadFile(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        if 'stackRast' not in locals():
            stackRast = aSrc
        else:
            stackRast = np.dstack([stackRast, aSrc])
```

I cannot test this myself, but hopefully the junk collection will free up some memory every loop. I reckon there may be a more efficient way to do `stackRast = np.dstack([stackRast, aSrc])`, but cannot think of it at the moment

Answer (score -3):

build a gdal VRT file containing a pointer to their address

Comment: and how should this be done? your answers lack explanation (IMHO)